# How can I match two strings by using substring in PROLOG?

Tags: prolog, substring, match

I have been developing expert system as a term project. And in the expert system, I am trying to make a function that will compare two strings including its substring. for example, it will be like:

let's say there's A = 'health_care', B = 'healthy_food'.
Because there's a partially matched string, 'health', it will result in 'true'.

I have tried to find some functions related to it, I could not find anything. If you have some ideas or specific solutions, it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: which prolog interpreter are you using? swi-prolog?

Comment: yes. I'm using swi-prolog.

Comment: also, can you define partially matched string? how many letters need to match?

Comment: I didn't thought about that specifically yet, but at least 4 letters in each string would be considered as a substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google: "prolog substring" gives this:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sub_string/5

You can use this to solve your problem like this. Increase the condition on L if you want to only admit longer sub-strings:

```
sub_string('testing', B, L, A, Sub),
sub_string('tester', B2, L, A2, Sub),
L > 3.
```

Comment: This predicate only appears to be available in SWI-Prolog. How would it be implemented for other Prolog versions?